# Can a URL be double encoded?

Tags: javascript, http, url, decode, encode

A basic encoded URL would usually comprise of a "?" and few "&". Can this url be double encoded to eliminate all "?" and all the "&". would it work? Is it right to do it?

Please check a sample encoded url -

```
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/example.html?var=This+is+a+simple+%26+short+test&testmail=the+master.
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent`, it will produce:

> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.permadi.com%2Ftutorial%2FurlEncoding%2Fexample.html%3Fvar%3DThis%20is%20a%20simple%20%26%20short%20test%26testmail%3Dthe%20master.%20

It should works in all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks, it does encode as required. But tried accessing some stackoverflow urls after encoding using encodeURIComponent(complete stackover url). was not accessible!